# PBR maps not working on Blender 4

Tags: node-editor, pbr

I have activated Node wrangler and node arrange on preference list, but still the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> not working. Is the shortcut different on Blender 4 or Mac Os have a different shortcut ?

Comment: do you have a principled shader node selected when pressing they key-combo?

Answer (score 0):

It has been all the time: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: ...or Cmd+Shift+T on a Mac...

Comment: Even on mac it's Ctrl+Shift+T